# Show that a map is an embedding

Tags: matrices, manifolds, submanifold

I guess that the image (all matricies of rank $2r$ with $r$ positive and $r$ negative eigenvalues) of the map

$$\psi: GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C}) \qquad A \mapsto A(-1_r \oplus {1}_r \oplus 0_{n-2r})A^*$$

is a manifold of dimension $4nr-4r^2$.

Maybe if I can show that $\psi$ is an embedding the problem is solved.

It should be clear that $\psi$ is injective but I don't know how to prove that it is open.

Comment: $\psi$ is certainly not injective. Consider $1_{2r} \oplus -1_{n-2r}$ and $1_n$.

Comment: Shouldn't $\psi$ give the singular value decomposition for some matrix (and so be unique in this form)? But you are right the sign is a problem.